# Need help to render img in pdf from template using xhtml2pdf

Tags: django, xhtml2pdf

I'm building a project were i need to get my data into pdf from a template (html), my problem is that the image is not apearing on pdf view.
This is my code:

```py
class GeneratePdf_month(TemplateView):

    template_name = "polls/info_month.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ## do some....
        data = {
            'cliente': cliente,
        }
        pdf = render_to_pdf(self.template_name, data)
        return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')


## and this is my html template
<head>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <title>Detail</title>
    <style>
        table, th, td {
          border: 1px solid black;
          border-collapse: collapse;
          padding: 10px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>BlaBla<img src="{% static 'polls/images/image.png'%}"></header>
</body
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5):

If your are using xhtmltopdf you also need to provide a link_callback for being abble to display images:

```
def link_callback(uri, rel):
    """
    Convert HTML URIs to absolute system paths so xhtml2pdf can access those
    resources
    """
    # use short variable names
    sUrl = settings.STATIC_URL     # Typically /static/
    #static Root
    sRoot = settings.STATIC_ROOT    # Typically /home/userX/project_static/
    mUrl = settings.MEDIA_URL       # Typically /static/media/
    mRoot = settings.MEDIA_ROOT     # Typically /home/userX/project_static/media/

    # convert URIs to absolute system paths
    if uri.startswith(mUrl):
        path = os.path.join(mRoot, uri.replace(mUrl, ""))
    elif uri.startswith(sUrl):
        path = os.path.join(sRoot, uri.replace(sUrl, ""))
    else:
        return uri  # handle absolute uri (ie: http://some.tld/foo.png)

    # make sure that file exists
    if not os.path.isfile(path):
            raise Exception(
                'media URI must start with %s or %s' % (sUrl, mUrl)
            )
    return path
```

AND don't forget to add the link callback in your render_to_pdf:

```
def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html = template.render(context_dict) 
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result, link_callback=link_callback)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf') 
    return None
```

You also need to specify the height and widht inside the img tag like:

```
<img src="{% static 'polls/images/image.png'%}" alt="image" width="200" height="150" />
```

In settings.py don't forget to define your STATIC_URL AND STATIC_ROOT, MEDIA_URL AND MEDIA_ROOT

Like this for exemple:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'project_name/static/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'project_name/media/')
```

**Then don't forget to run** `python manage.py collectstatic` **in the terminal**

More info here: https://xhtml2pdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#using-xhtml2pdf-in-django

Comment: can you show your static settings and render_to_pdf function?

Comment: def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html  = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None

Comment: Updated, need to add link_callback when you create the pisaDocument

Comment: ```python pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result, link_callback=link_callback) ```

Comment: i changed to this and still does not render de image

Comment: can you share your static settings?

Comment: i haven't changed much on settings.py, my static url : ```python STATIC_URL = '/static/'```

Comment: You need to define a STATIC_ROOT as well or in sRoot in link_callback do the same trick I did.

Comment: It should work like this ``` STATIC_ROOT = '/static/' ```

Comment: no STATIC_ROOT should be the absolute path to your project staticfolder

Comment: ok, o made it like this : ```STATIC_ROOT = '/home/zigko/Desktop/django_projects/mysite/polls/static/' ``` and still doesn't apear de image on my pdf :(

Comment: you also need to define height and width in the img tag otherwise it will not work

Comment: `<img src="{% static 'polls/images/image.png'%}" alt="image" width="200" height="150" />`

Comment: try to add the picture inside the static folder at the root of the project(and not in static folder of the app)

Comment: i changed this: ``` STATIC_ROOT = '/home/zigko/Desktop/django_projects/mysite/static/' ``` and ```  <img src="{% static 'images/image.png'%}" alt="image" width="200" height="150" /> ``` and is not working again...

Comment: did you put the img inside: '/home/zigko/Desktop/django_projects/mysite/static/images/image.png' ? and create the folder accordingly?

Comment: I edit and test my answer with a project from scratch and it's working. Be sure to follow all the steps

Comment: Has anyone gotten this to work in the xhtmltopdf styles in the header of your template? It doesn't seem to be working in the css like this: `background-image: url("{% static 'img/image.pdf' %}");` I'm trying to use a PDF as a background image in the PDF I'm creating. It works if I supply an absolute URL, but not using Django's staticfiles tag.

Comment: So i have done everything and its not working. No image on pdf but then I got to know that xhtml2pdf is not allowing every package of CSS. https://xhtml2pdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=css#supported-css-properties Please check out this link.I am stuck here and its like a dead end with all that error like "getFile '/static/css/style.css' '/home/jimitrupani/Desktop/mysite' '/home/jimitrupani/Desktop/mysite'"  "Exception: media URI must start with /static/ or /media/"

Answer (score 0):

in views.py

```
        from pathlib import Path

        BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
        path = os.path.join( BASE_DIR , 'static') 
        # send 'path' first in context
        context = {'path':path , 'any':any }
```

in template

```
     <img src="{{path}}\img\pic.png"  >
```